# URI management and navigation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, uri

I'd like to implement a special routing in rails based on the URI (I'm using rails 3.0.4 with Mongoid and devise). Let's say my user logins, once signin I want to redirect him to a private area for example http://www.mysite.com/site1. Many users could belong to site1, many to site2... users of one site are not authorized to see another site. Today the redirection is fine after sign in, but I'm confused on how I should implement siteX (each site has its own data). I have the following route:

```
match '/:site_name' => 'site#index', :constraints => { :site_name => /'a pattern'/ }
  resources :sites do
end
```

Because I need to stick to this URI format should I nest all my other resources inside :sites? For example if I want to display order 1 of site 2 the URL should look like http://www.mysite.com/site2/order/1. I can't put the resource's name "sites" in the URI as it starts directly with the identifier. Is there another way of doing this, what would be the best pratices? Hope my explanations make sense.

Thanks a lot for all your help!
Ted

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you scrap the idea of "subdirectories".  You'll have (not insurmountable) difficulties with `link_to` and the other helpers.

I would setup subdomains (a la, site1.mysite.com) if that's possible for your situation

Answer (score 0):

Doing `url.com/site_name` is kind of nuts.

If only one user can belong to a site, take it from the user perspective then and use `resource` and not `resources`.

E.g., `url.com/orders` would be all current_user.orders, since current_user has_one site (or is a member of one site).

If you need site specific navigation, then draw from `/site_name` for site specific detail that is public in nature.  E.g., `url.com/site_name/pricing`

If you really want to break your site down into `/site_name` specific routes, then through that into a subdomain.  You can even try using [sudomain devise](https://github.com/fortuity/rails3-subdomain-devise) to get you started.